# How to refer to a column variable by its name?

Tags: dolphindb

[image]

My script is as shown above, where `col` is a string variable. How can I use the column names (string variables) to refer to column variables?How can I modify the script to ensure a successful execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the above script, we can infer that you want to fill the NULL values in the column. You can use the `nullFill` function:

```
t = table(1.0 2.0 NULL 3.3 as open, NULL 1.3 NULL 2.2 as low)
nullFill(t, 0)
```

In `tb_fj[col, <isNull(col)>]`, `col` must be a column variable, rather than a string. You can refer to the following code:

```
id = 1..10
x = rand(NULL 10.0, 10)
t  = table(id, x as x1)
colName=`x1
t[colName, isNull(t[colName])] = 0
```

In other cases, you can use `objByName` to return a variable by its name, and `funcByName` to execute a function by its name. In SQL metaprogramming, you can use `sqlCol` to return a column by its name.